# Hibernate/JPA MSSQL replaces Brackets with `

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am dealing with a database that has column with spaces. So I try to enclose the Column in brackets like this...

```
@Column(name = "[Licensee Address]")
```

However when I run the app. Hibernate replaces Brackets with this

```
`Licensee Address`
```

Which throws a error

```
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

MSSQL uses brackets not quotes. How do I fix this ??

When I do it without the brackets it generates the following sql...

```
Hibernate: select licenseein0_.WRRAppID as WRRAppID1_1_0_, licenseein0_.ApplicantTypeID as Applican2_1_0_, licenseein0_.BusinessActivity as Business3_1_0_, licenseein0_.CompanyID as CompanyI4_1_0_, licenseein0_.CreatedBy as CreatedB5_1_0_, licenseein0_.CreatedDate as CreatedD6_1_0_, licenseein0_.DBAName as DBAName7_1_0_, licenseein0_.FCCCallSign as FCCCallS8_1_0_, licenseein0_.FCCFileNumber as FCCFileN9_1_0_, licenseein0_.FCCRegistration# as FCCRegi10_1_0_, licenseein0_.FedTaxID# as FedTaxI11_1_0_, licenseein0_.LicenseActionID as License12_1_0_, licenseein0_.LicenseeName as License13_1_0_, licenseein0_.RadioService as RadioSe14_1_0_, licenseein0_.RadioUse as RadioUs15_1_0_, licenseein0_.SubmittedDate as Submitt16_1_0_ from Licensee_Information licenseein0_ where licenseein0_.WRRAppID=?
```

And the error message I get is...

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Comment: SQUARE BRACKETS are not the way to define a case sensitive column name. Using quotes (single or double dependent on your RDBMS) is the way

Comment: I am using mssql and I've tried single, double, and brackets. they all fail. And hibernate changes my double quotes into single quotes. double quotes work in the query when I run it in the DB. but hibernate changes them to single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Had to incorrect hibernate dialect set up. It must be the following

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name isn't `[Licensee Address]`, the column name is `Licensee Address`. If you remove the `[` and `]` it should work. If you are writing a query in T-SQL and you need to reference a column named with a space, special characters or reserved words, you need to put the `[` and `]` so the query parser knows where the column name starts and stops. But you are not writing T-SQL, so you don't need to do that.

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't work. It says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.` I've update my information that shows what it does without quotes.